# COUNTIF() in Excel (Office 2013)

Tags: excel, office-2013

Dear All I want to Eliminate the possibility of entering a Duplicate item in a range. I used `=COUNTIF($C$3:$C$151,C3)<=1` in Excel (office 2013) in Custom Data Validation. Below is the Error I get. I am not able to figure it out. Please give your input.  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=COUNTIF( $C$3:$C$151; C3 ) <= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 =countif(range, criteria)

 =countif($C$1:$C$151, "<=1")   'better formula
```